# How to write data to existing process's STDIN from external process?

Tags: linux, process, stdin, file-descriptor, tty

I'm seeking for ways to write data to the existing process's `STDIN` from external processes, and found similar question  [How do you stream data into the STDIN of a program from different local/remote processes in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3792054/how-do-you-stream-data-into-the-stdin-of-a-program-from-different-local-remote-pr) in stackoverlow.

In that thread, @Michael says that we can get file descriptors of existing process in path like below, and permitted to write data into them on Linux.

```
/proc/$PID/fd/
```

So, I've created a simple script listed below to test writing data to the script's `STDIN` (and `TTY`) from external process.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys

def get_ttyname():
    for f in sys.stdin, sys.stdout, sys.stderr:
        if f.isatty():
            return os.ttyname(f.fileno())
    return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Try commands below")

    print("$ echo 'foobar' > {0}".format(get_ttyname()))
    print("$ echo 'foobar' > /proc/{0}/fd/0".format(os.getpid()))

    print("read :: [" + sys.stdin.readline() + "]")
```

This test script shows paths of `STDIN` and `TTY` and then, wait for one to write it's `STDIN`.

I launched this script and got messages below.

```
Try commands below
$ echo 'foobar' > /dev/pts/6
$ echo 'foobar' > /proc/3308/fd/0
```

So, I executed the command `echo 'foobar' > /dev/pts/6` and `echo 'foobar' > /proc/3308/fd/0` from other terminal. After execution of both commands, message `foobar` is displayed twice on the terminal the test script is running on, but that's all. The line `print("read :: [" + sys.stdin.readline() + "]")` was not executed.

Are there any ways to write data from external processes to the existing process's `STDIN` (or other file descriptors), i.e. invoke execution of the line`print("read :: [" + sys.stdin.readline() + "]")` from other processes?

Comment: Would a named pipe (see `man mkfifo`) do what you want?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your code will not work.
`/proc/pid/fd/0` is a link to the `/dev/pts/6` file.

> $ echo 'foobar' > /dev/pts/6
>   $ echo 'foobar' > /proc/pid/fd/0

Since both the commands write to the terminal. This input goes to terminal and not to the process.

It will work if stdin intially is a pipe.
For example, `test.py` is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os, sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Try commands below")
    print("$ echo 'foobar' > /proc/{0}/fd/0".format(os.getpid()))
    while True:
        print("read :: [" + sys.stdin.readline() + "]")
        pass
```

Run this as:

```
$ (while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; done) | python test.py
```

Now from another terminal write something to `/proc/pid/fd/0` and it will come to `test.py`

Comment: Script and command you suggested works correctly. So, once I created the process from terminal without pipe like `$ python test.py`, there are no way to execute `print("read :: [" + sys.stdin.readline() + "]")` from external process?

Comment: @mooz: AFAIK there is no way to do that.

Comment: @mooz ... Your 'client-side' can use the command `source fifo-file-name`.  Perhaps you could do that with a start-up script like a special `.bashrc` ???

Comment: Is there any advantage to `(while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; done) | python test.py` rather than the much simpler `cat | python test.py` described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32643326/6243352)?

Answer (score 8):

I want to leave here an example I found useful. It's a slight modification of the while true trick above that failed intermittently on my machine.

```
# pipe cat to your long running process
( cat ) | ./your_server &
server_pid=$!
# send an echo to your cat process that will close cat and in my hypothetical case the server too
echo "quit\n" > "/proc/$server_pid/fd/0"
```

It was helpful to me because for particular reasons I couldn't use `mkfifo`, which is perfect for this scenario.