# Python command line argument for an existing process

Tags: python, linux, process, arguments

I am trying to write a script for controling cpu usage of a VM n KVM using cpulimit. With cpulimit i can limit the cpu usage of a VM with pid say 2112 by :

> ./cpulimit -p 2112 -l 50.

I want to write a script which can open an interface

> setcpu (vm_pid,limit)

Which can be called any number of times and I shud overwrite the existing limit. I can overwrite the existing limit by just adding the limit value as a runtime argument for the running cpulimit process. Like subprocess.Popen(..., stdin=subprocess.PIPE). I am a bit confused on how to grab the running process and provide runtime argument. For example (without scripting) :

> # ./cpulimit -p 2112 -l 50
>
> ```
>  Process 2112 detected
> ```

Now It will set a cap on the process, Now I can simply enter

> 40
>
> 80

to overwrite the existing limit. I want to script this behavior . It will be great if you can provide a pointer or an idea on how to go about writing this script. Thanks a lot

- Sethu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: If you need to talk to an existing `cpulimit`, you should look at the accepted answer to [How to write data to existing process's STDIN from external process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process)

Basically, do

```
(while [ 1 ]; do sleep 1; done) | ./cpulimit -p 2112 -l 50.
```

when you start `cpulimit`, because it's input needs to be a pipe.

Then, from Python write to `/proc/{pid_of_cpulimit}/fd/0`.

---

If you've spawned a process with

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['./cpulimit', '-p', '2112', '-l', '50'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

just do

```
process.communicate(input='40')
process.communicate(input='80')
```

Comment: +1 for Popen, but `communicate` is no good - it closes stdin and waits for the process to terminate. You should write to process.stdin instead.

Comment: @orip I have read that to interact directly with stdin/stdout is prone to race condition. Isn't that true?

Comment: @brandizzi maybe you mean this issue which is only relevant for multithreaded code: http://bugs.python.org/issue2320, their final analysis shows the concurrency error happens even without stdin=PIPE. Interesting.

Comment: I've edited my answer; what I've posted should work if you start `cpulimit` with a pipe for it's `stdin`.

Comment: I have just one doubt ? Why are we writing to 2112 ? That will be the VM right ? If I have to write , it shud be to the terminal of the cpulimit process right ?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

Open a subprocess like agf shows, don't forget to specify that `stdin` is piped:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen("./cpulimit -p 2112 -l 50", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Then write to `p.stdin`:

```
p.stdin.write("40\n")
p.stdin.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For the first time it will work. But consider the script terminates after spawning the process and setting the initial limit. And after a second, if that api is called. I will not be able to proceed and write p.stdin.write("40\n"). That is the case I am worried about. Is it possible to spawn from a process ID? I will be able to retrieve the process id of the running cpulimit instance.

Comment: Why would the subprocess terminate? If climit waits for stdin to close, it should stay alive.

Comment: He means that the Python script isn't spawning the process; he needs to do it to an existing `cpulimit`.

Comment: @agf yeah , I want to do it to an existing process.

Comment: Look at my edited answer, I show you how, and link to a post with more details.