# Reattaching to spawned process via nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, process, stdio, child-process

I am creating a small proprietary game server manager in Node.js; currently it runs the game by spawning via `child_process`:

```
var server = spawn(cmd, args, { cwd: 'something' });
```

So long as the manager continues to run I can pipe commands and deal with the child as I would like. However, consider the possibility that my manager crashes or is closed. How would I then *reattach*  to the previously spawned child process (which was still running while the manager was down)? I can store pidfiles to try and reconnect based on pid; but I'm not sure how to get a `child_process` object with  access to the child's `stdio` objects.

I really would like this to be recoverable; any help is appreciated, thanks!

---

**Please note**: The game servers are proprietary, some examples are Minecraft, Source DS, etc. Assume i do not have access to the sever source.

---

**EDIT**

After reading some source code from node's `child_process` it looks like if you specify a property in the options called `stdinStream`, `stdoutStream`, or `stderrStream` it should just open a socket to it. (See lines [428](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/child_process.js#L428) - [496](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/child_process.js#L496)). So the issue then is, how do I stop spawn from *actually* doing a spawn and instead just settings its values based on a specified pid and streams I pass. (I would get my `stdinStream` by doing `fs.createWriteStream('/proc/PID/fd/0');` which should work since that fd is created as a pipe.)

Comment: hmm. I wonder if you could do that in ANY programming language, let alone js / node. If it were me, I'd take a look at using sockets to solve this

Comment: I pass through some commands via `stdin` of the child process, since I have little experience with *nix sockets how could I accomplish regaining a 'pipe' to the child's `stdin`?

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After speaking with some of the guys on the node project, it looks like the only way I can accomplish this is by dealing with the raw file descriptors in the proc fs. I will probably mock up something similar to a `child_process` object and create its streams like:

```
var child = {};
child.stdin = fs.createWriteStream('/proc/PID/fd/0');
child.stdout = fs.createReadStream('/proc/PID/fd/1');
child.stderr = fs.createReadStream('/proc/PID/fd/2');
```

Comment: Does this method still work? I can't seem to get it to work with Node v0.10. I am trying to make a Minecraft server admin and would like some insight if you have any. :)

Comment: I never got this to work 100% on 0.6 so I abandoned trying to do something like this unfortunately :/

Comment: Sad day, looks like I may have to follow suit.

Comment: Have either of you ever looked at this again? Reconnecting to child processes? @DominicBarnes

Answer (score 1):

To extend what someone said in a comment above, you may be able to use http://nodejs.org/api/net.html where each child process creates a server (`net.createServer()`) and you keep a list of what children are listening at what ports somewhere, and then when your master restarts, it goes and finds that list of children and connects to each their servers. The `Sockets` that you get from `net.createConnection()` replace the `child_process` objects in your master.

`net` servers and sockets implement the same Readable and Writable [Stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) interfaces as `stdio`, so after setting up and connecting, you should be able to `write(...)` and `pipe()` events like you've been doing.

This may not be the best solution but I believe it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately this would mean spinning up a node instance for each game server I would need to run, and if any of those children crash or are closed I'm in the exact same boat.

Comment: True, its a lot of new node instances, but I thought spawn did that too. I don't follow about being in the same boat if one crashes, of course you'd have to restart it, but this way you can reconnect with the existing stuff.

Comment: You are talking about have a master node proc spawn children node procs and communicate with them through sockets, which is fine and recoverable. But that *child* node proc would spawn its game server and communicate with it through `stdin`. So if that *child* crashes you can reconnect to a new child but that child cant reconnect to the game server, which is the entire problem. A game server can be a java process, a source dedicated server, anything really.

Comment: Aah, I was thinking pure-node. However, the net/socket idea might still work for the node-to-game communication if you're also writing the game code. If it must be `stdin` though, then my answer is pretty useless. It's a bit outside of my knowledge, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process might have some useful info.