# sending input from file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, file-descriptor

I have a binary that I'm debugging remotely, one way for me to send input to that file is throw

```
echo "input" > /proc/pid/fd/0
```

when I do the above the input is been received by the binary but I can't simulate a keypress, and that causes me to switch to that binary and press enter every time.

here is an example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
   char str[50];

   printf("Enter a string : ");
   gets(str);

   printf("You entered: %s", str);

   return(0);
}
```

when you run the above program and send the input using

```
echo "input" > /proc/pid/fd/0
```

the above program will receive the input but it will not press the enter key

so is there is a way to do it using the file descriptor of the binary or any quick way?

*in my case keypress is just the enter key*

edit:

```
echo -en 'input\r' > /proc/pid/fd/0
```

or

```
echo -en 'input\x0d' > /proc/pid/fd/0
```

won't work because the terminal will think it's the slave sending that to the output it will not be sent to slave's stdin

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write data to existing process's STDIN from external process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374255/how-to-write-data-to-existing-processs-stdin-from-external-process)

Comment: Also a cross-site duplicate of [Writing to stdin of a process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/385771/217726) and [Why does writing to the console a process's STDIN is attached to doesn't send input to the application itself?](https://serverfault.com/q/947247/402194)

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica it turns out that those didn't solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you have your process read from a named pipe (`mkfifo`)?  Then keyboard input is possible with `cat > mypipe`, but while that `cat` is running, you can also `echo foo > mypipe`, because a pipe can have multiple writers (I think.)

Otherwise you're going to want something like `expect` to connect your program to a pseudo-terminal, with another program managing the master side.

---

> `echo "input" > /proc/pid/fd/0`  the above program will receive the input

No, the output will show up in the terminal exactly as if you did `echo "input" > /dev/pts/12` or whatever terminal device the process has open as its stdin (usually with the same read/write file descriptor for all 3 of stdin, stdout, and stderr, which is why it works to write to it).

For the program to be able to `read()` your input, you'd need to write to the other side of the pseudo-terminal, which is probably owned by `ssh` or a terminal emulator.  It *might* be possible to write to one of the FDs of `ssh` or `xterm` or whatever.